# Webpack does not run in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: webpack, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Webpack does not run or give any error messages in windows subsystem for linux.

E.g. attempting to print the version number just exits silently with no errors:

```
node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -v
```

Other node packages e.g. babel.js run ok. These are the installed versions:

- ubuntu: 16_04
- node: 8.4
- webpack: 3.5.5
- Windows: 10.0.15063

Comment: It might be also because WSL2 is much slower than WSL1 and Microsoft has admitted that on github. Maybe it has taken too long and you thought it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh - some unknown npm issue - deleting node_modules and reinstalling fixed it